# React router v0.13.3 or v1.0.0-beta3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I want to build a basic app using react, flux (redux) and react-router. It will be a isomorphic (universal) app. I am confused about which react-router version should i use?

0.13.3 or 1.0.0-beta3.

Asking because 1.0 is cool and has better support for isomorphic apps and have simplified other things as well but it's still in beta.

Anybody knows when will 1.0 finalized?

Comment: If you can go with the 1.0beta, it will save you some trouble along the road,  otherwise you will have to incorporate the API changes eventually.

Comment: @Eelke You are right ...Thanks! Just was curious if there is any downside to using 1.0.0beta3

Answer (score 1):

Providing the module maintainers follow [semver](http://semver.org/) correctly then the following are some things you should be aware of when using a `0.x.x` versus `1.x.x` version.

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

In this case there is the added complication of the `-beta3` which I would take to mean that the interface has been locked down but there may be bugs.

From the comments above, @Eelke is correct in that you *may* save time in the future by going straight to `1.0.0-beta3` but beware that you will be working with an unproven version.

My advice would be that if you're looking to put this into production in a critical application where you may need some support then stick with the `0.13.3` for now. If you have the time to 'go deep', dig around in the code (if you have to) and help the maintainers with feedback/bug reports then use `1.0.0-beta3`